# Is this the correct way of rendering a yield content_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionview, actionviewhelper

```
<%= yield(:title_box) if content_for?(:title_box) %>
```

**Or is the if condition useless here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition check is not needed as if nothing to render there is nothing will be outputted. See [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html)